# heroku & django: server doesn't load staticfiles

Tags: css, django, git, heroku, django-staticfiles

Last night I decided to put my django school project on production. For this I used Heroku. Everything is going fine but "the last touch" is driving me crazy. It seems that it doesn't see my staticfiles like bootstrap css'es on the website and I don't know why because for example the ball.jpg is loaded and the admin css are loaded too. If someone could find the problem that I'm dealing with for the last 10h it would be a life saver :)

You can see the results [here](http://footballapp.herokuapp.com/)

My settings.py

```
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.DEBUG:
import os
import dj_database_url
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'team',
    'tournament',
    'geoposition',
    'emailing',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'football.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'football.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = settings.DATABASES
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static asset configuration
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media", "static_root")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_in_pro", "static"),
)


# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'


# MEDIA SETTINGS
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media", "media_root")

# CRISPY FORM SETTINGS
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

# Django-Geoposition
GEOPOSITION_MAP_OPTIONS = {
    'minZoom': 8,
    'maxZoom': 15,
    'center': {'lat': 53.13248859999999,
               'lng': 23.168840300000056 },
}

GEOPOSITION_MAP_WIDGET_HEIGHT = 240

GEOPOSITION_MARKER_OPTIONS = {
    'cursor': 'move'
}
```

While Git pushing

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Running collectstatic...
remote:        Post-processed 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' as 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.140919a6a17e.js'
(...)
remote:        82 static files copied to '/app/media/static_root', 82 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 48.6MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v51
remote:        https://footballapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
```

My heroku logs --tail:

```
2015-11-15T20:37:12.426289+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-15T20:37:12.426301+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-15T20:37:12.456467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-15T20:37:16.171136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn football.wsgi`
2015-11-15T20:37:16.794898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-15T20:37:17.969513+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:17 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2015-11-15T20:37:17.956039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-11-15T20:37:17.956047+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-11-15T20:37:17.956935+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:17 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2015-11-15T20:37:18.765840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-11-15T20:37:18.579708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:18 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46020 (3)
2015-11-15T20:37:18.579713+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:18 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-11-15T20:37:18.588372+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:18 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2015-11-15T20:37:18.578828+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:18 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
2015-11-15T20:37:18.655018+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:37:18 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2015-11-15T20:37:19.993385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-15T20:37:26.757037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=16bde5f5-98bd-48a0-bde4-269947950c15 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=114ms status=200 bytes=4597
2015-11-15T20:37:27.090478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/img/cartoon-soccer-6.3dda712041b4.jpg" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=726fdf17-a3bb-4edc-94ee-8e0291c4fb68 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=24769
2015-11-15T20:37:27.314794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/npm.ccb7f3909e30.js" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d22d2938-6955-4c0a-9c30-71a2dc408106 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=566
2015-11-15T20:37:27.299303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.8015042d0b4a.js" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=afceaef7-b06c-4523-b855-f6966a2829fa fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=14380
2015-11-15T20:37:43.569729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ab185988-12f4-4b78-a7d7-53eae067e891 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=4597
2015-11-15T20:37:43.769540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/img/cartoon-soccer-6.3dda712041b4.jpg" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=e01d8276-1220-45f8-b9b1-866cd5ab2e7d fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=24769
2015-11-15T20:37:44.086677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/npm.ccb7f3909e30.js" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=3172e050-63d5-421d-b3b2-cca661739c34 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=566
2015-11-15T20:37:44.064945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static_root/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.8015042d0b4a.js" host=footballapp.herokuapp.com request_id=06b09fae-36db-4ac2-9d8d-fe0a2b3cfb06 fwd="178.42.56.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=14380
2015-11-15T20:38:54.229389+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b75838d by tofik1432@gmail.com
2015-11-15T20:38:54.229389+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v51 created by tofik1432@gmail.com
2015-11-15T20:38:54.375061+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-15T20:38:54.375070+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-15T20:38:54.509049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-15T20:38:57.508059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn football.wsgi`
2015-11-15T20:38:59.282919+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:38:59 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
2015-11-15T20:38:59.349517+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:38:59 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2015-11-15T20:38:59.283351+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:38:59 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57838 (3)
2015-11-15T20:38:59.283475+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:38:59 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-11-15T20:38:59.286946+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:38:59 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2015-11-15T20:38:59.734335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-15T20:39:00.743234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-15T20:39:02.232759+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:39:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-11-15T20:39:02.232763+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:39:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-11-15T20:39:02.252311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:39:02 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2015-11-15T20:39:02.297059+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-15 20:39:02 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

EDIT:
I Found out that it seems not to load my include html's to the base.html, anyone had this problem?

Comment: Is this your first heroku app? It seems that heroku some trouble serving static files for the second app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Heroku recently. It seems that Django cannot serve static assets by itself on production. I was able to use [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve the statics instead. First install it:

`$ pip install whitenoise`

Make sure you add `whitenoise` to your `requirements.txt` as well.

Now add the following to your **wsgi.py**:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Finally, configure whitenoise in your settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

or depending on which versions of Django and WhiteNoise you are running:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Also, make sure you have your statics correctly configured in your **settings.py**

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets